# How to pull data from database and store it asynchronously in NUXT

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to the NUXTjs framework and I am looking for the best way to pull from a db and store it asynchronously.

Comment: You might want to explain in more detail what you mean by "store asynchronously".

Comment: you might want to look things around $store and asyncData https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ - but as mentioned by Farhad you'll need some form of API you can hit into - express ... at other scale you could want to look at loopback.io

Answer (score 0):

Nuxtjs is for client purpose, and for pulling data from a database you have to use another server like Hapijs or Express.

roadmap:

1: You use nuxtjs to feed browser with SSR(Server side rendering ) in vuejs "SSR for SEO purpose".

2: You need another server like Hapijs to pull or store data in a database.